# How to have a smooth transition when showing / hiding text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to switch between the short and the full  description of an article. Actually i have this markup

```
<div class="post-content">
<p class="corta">Antonio Colombo Contemporary Art and Atelier Biagetti, have the honour to present&nbsp;a</p>
<span class="points" >...</span>
<br />
<span style="display:none" class="completa">Here i have the full description
</span>
<a style="width:auto;" class="link readLess" href="#">read more</a>
</div>
```

and this js

```
$('div.post-content').delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $(this).closest('div');
    var points = div.find('.points');
    var complete = div.find('.completa').html();
    var corta = div.find('.corta').html();
    div.find('.corta').html(complete);
    div.find('.completa').html(corta);
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('readMore')) {
        $this.text("read less");
        $this.addClass('readLess').removeClass('readMore');
        points.show();
    } else {
        $this.text("read more");
        $this.addClass('readMore').removeClass('readLess');
        points.hide();
    }

});
```

This works ok, but id rather have a smooth transition between the short and long description. What would you suggest?
I could change the markup or use a jQuery plugin if neded

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ycdBH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed. look at http://jsfiddle.net/ycdBH/9/

Comment: This is nice, i ended up using slideDown (like another poster suggested) http://jsfiddle.net/ycdBH/7/

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery UI function `switchClass` you can animate the switching between two classes

ref : http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/

Comment: That's nice, but here i'm switching content, not classes, the area increases becuase there is more text! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.show('slow')
.hide('slow')
```

YOu can use duration instead of slow.